# Unable to solve error: linker command failed with exit code 1

Tags: c++, xcode

Trying to create a class Account but i keep getting "linker command failed with exit code 1" everytime I build. Any suggestions would be highly appreciated, for I have been trying to solve this problem for a few days now.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Account
{
public:
Account();
Account(double input_balance);

void input();
private:
double balance;
};


Account::Account()
{   
double balance = 0.0;
}
Account::Account(double input_balance)
{
double balance = input_balance;
}

void Account::input()
{
char in;
    cout << "Would you like to deposit or withdraw money from your account?    Enter D for deposit and W for withdraw: ";
cin >> in;

if(in == 'd' || in == 'D')
    cout << "Yo";
if(in == 'w' || in == 'W')
    cout << "no";
}

int main()
{
Account tyler;
tyler.input();
}
```

Comment: `double balance = 0.0;` in `Account::Account()` doesnt initialize the member variable, this declares a new local variable and initializes that to `0.0` (you made the same error in the other constructor)

Comment: Is that the full error?

Comment: [cannot reproduce](https://ideone.com/bMCYru)